# Convert json to XML with namespace and tokens in Scala

Tags: scala, xstream

I have a json document like this:

```
{"orderNumber": "12345",
"date": "11/05/2011",
"fromInventoryLocation": "New York",
"toLocation": "Los Angeles",
"shippingMethod": "Ground",
"shipDate": "11/25/2014",
"shipTo": "123 Main St.",
"Items": [
   {"item": "shirt", "quantity": "2", "orderPriority": "Standard"}, 
]}
```

I initialize the XStream converter with:

`val xstreamIB = xstream.XStreamConversions(new XStream(new DomDriver))`

I use a case class Shipment to create the object and pass it to:

`val xmlIB = xstreamIB.toXML(Shipment)`

The output XML file returns:

```
<Shipment>
  <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
  <Date>11/05/2011</Date>
  <Address>
    <Street>123 Main St.</Street>
  </Address>
  <Etc>
    <Ex>...</Ex>
  </Etc>
</Shipment
```

The receiving API requires 2 things.  A namespace in the opening Shipment tag; `<Shipment xmlns="namespace">`, and a token in the address tag; `<Address type = "shipping">`.  I tried using .alias, but it modifies both the open and closing tag; throwing an error.

Is there a way to add the namespace and the token into the opening tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the xml namespace using StaxDriver instead of DomDriver.  The code below worked:

```
val qmap = new QNameMap
  qmap.setDefaultNamespace("urn:namespace")
  val xmlOut = xstream.XStreamConversions(new XStream(new StaxDriver(qmap)))
val xml = xmlOut.toXML(Shipment)
```